# Filtrar registros con checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una gran duda espero me puedan ayudar, tengo una base de datos la cual puedo visualizar en una pagina web, pero tengo que **filtrar** mediante checkbox (y que estos sea alimentados de las mismas opciones que cuenta la BD)

**Ejemplo:**
Si quiero filtrar por País y en mi BD tengo los países (México, Colombia, Bolivia y España) serían 4 checkbox.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que quieres:

lista_paises.php

```
<?php
        include "funciones.php";
        connect(); //FUNCION PARA CONECTAR A MYSQL, incluida en funciones.php
?>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Pagina ejemplo </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY >
<?php
        $query_pais="select nombre from pais";
        $result_query=MySQL_query($query_pais) or die(MySQL_error());
        while ($filas=MySQL_fetch_array($result_query))
        {
                extract($filas);
                $output_php.=<<<EOD
                <input type="checkbox" name=$pais_nombre>$pais_nombre
                <br>
EOD;
        }
        echo $output_php;
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si jalas los paises de la BD, solo guardalos en un array y los muestras con HTML. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php 
 foreach($paises as $id => $pais) { 
  //array(4) {[1]=>"México", [2]=>"Colombia", [3]=>"Bolivia", [4]=>"España"}
?> 
<input type="checkbox" name="pais[]" value="<?=$id;?>"><label><?= $pais; ?></label></input>
<?php } ?>
```

El "foreach" aquí lo que hace es iterar cada elemento del array y desplegar un checkbox con la información correspondiente al elemento. El resultado final quedaría algo así:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pais[]" id="1"/><label>México4</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="pais[]" id="2"/><label>Colombia</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="pais[]" id="3"/><label>Bolivia</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="pais[]" id="4"/><label>España</label>
```

Comment: Debes añadir una explicación de lo que hace el código que has puesto para poder ayudar al OP a entender cual es el problema que tenia.